# form with ajax either only usable once or doesn't update until refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use javascript to update a table of collaborators on a wiki app built in rails, adding them from another table of existing users on the same page. Initially, when I added a collaborator, the collaborator create action would only run once, and I had to refresh the page in order to add another. I tried adding .ajax(cache: false) to my javascript, and now I can add multiple collaborators without a refresh, but they don't show on the collaborators table or disappear from the users list until I refresh the page.

Here's my javascript:

```
<% if @collaborator.valid? %>
  $('.js-collaborators').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'collaborators/collaborator') %>").ajax(cache: false);
  $('.new-collaborator').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'collaborators/users', locals: { wiki: @wiki }) %>").ajax(cache: false);
<% else %>
  $('.new-collaborator').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'collaborators/users', locals: { wiki: @wiki }) %>").ajax(cache: false);
<% end %>`
```

Collaborator partial:

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width:75%">
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <% @wiki.collaborators.each do |collaborator| %>
    <tr>
      <% user = User.find(collaborator.user_id) %>
      <td><%= user.user_name %></td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to 'Remove', [@wiki, collaborator], method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger', remote: true %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Users partial:

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width:75%">
  <% User.all.each do |user| %>
  <% if !@wiki.collaborators.pluck(:user_id).include?(user.id) %>
    <%= form_for [@wiki, @wiki.collaborators.build], remote: true do |f| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.user_name %></td>
        <td>
          <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => user.id %>
          <%= f.submit 'Add', class: 'btn btn-xs btn-success', method: :create %>   
        <% end %>  
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Relevant part of the wiki show page:

```
<div class="js-collaborators">
  <%= render partial: 'collaborators/collaborator', locals: {wiki: @wiki} %>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#add-collaborators">Add Collaborators</button>
<div id="add-collaborators" class="new-collaborator collapse" >  
  <%= render partial: 'collaborators/users', locals: {wiki: @wiki} %>
</div>
```

I'm guessing setting the cache to false wasn't the ideal way to fix the initial problem of needing to refresh the page to add another collaborator, but I'm not sure what else to try. I'm very new to both rails and javascript. Thanks!

Edit: I changed my javascript to use .reset() instead of .ajax(cache: false). With that, my collaborators list updates correctly, but the user list does not. Here's the updated javascript:

```
<% if @collaborator.valid? %>
  $('.js-collaborators').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'collaborators/collaborator') %>").reset();
  $('.new-collaborator').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'collaborators/users') %>").reset();
<% else %>
  $('.new-collaborator').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'collaborators/users') %>").reset();
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hard to read that code, but how are you firing the AJAX event? Is it when the user presses a button, or when something changes? Have you tried resetting the form (form.reset()) after you get the info from the AJAX request?

Comment: The event is fired when the user clicks the Add button. I just tried adding .reset() to my javascript and that got me part way there. Now when I click Add, the new collaborator shows up on the collaborators list, but they aren't removed from the users list. I'll keep playing with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding an ID to the row in the users table, and having my javascript hide that row when adding the user as a collaborator instead of re-rendering the partial.

New javascript:

```
<% if @collaborator.valid? %>
  $('#user-' +<%= @collaborator.user_id %>).hide();
  $('.js-collaborators').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'collaborators/collaborator') %>").reset();
<% else %>
  $('.new-collaborator').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'collaborators/users') %>").reset();
<% end %>
```

New users table:

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width:75%">
  <% User.all.each do |user| %>
  <% if !@wiki.collaborators.pluck(:user_id).include?(user.id) %>
    <%= form_for [@wiki, @wiki.collaborators.build], remote: true do |f| %>
      <tr id='user-<%=user.id%>' >
        <td><%= user.user_name %></td>
        <td>
          <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => user.id %>
          <%= f.submit 'Add', class: 'btn btn-xs btn-success', method: :create %>   
        <% end %>  
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
</table>
```